# Tomcat with CDI: same project and different results at deploy

Tags: tomcat, cdi

I'm facing some problems during Tomcat startup with JSF (CDI/Weld). The biggest problem is, at work, this same project starts however at home it don't initializes.

Today I copied the functional log of work (Linux with Java 8) to compare with my log at home (Windows with Java 8) and it's: [console log at home and at work](https://www.diffnow.com/?report=yvfj1). *Note at line 210 in "Home Log", Tomcat deploys some application at /docs folder however in "Work Log" he put in /host-manager.*

I'm using Maven and Git to facilitate reuse of archives, so, basically, its the same project at my working stations (both projects are at last commit).

- JSF version `2.3.0-m04`
- Weld version `3.0.0.Alpha1`
- Omnifaces version `2.1`
- Apache Tomcat version `8.0.28`

Here's my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
version="2.5">
  <display-name>sgcp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

and `context.xml`

```
<Context>
    <Manager pathname="" />
    <Resource name="BeanManager" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
        factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

and folder structure

[image: folder structure.png]

Comment: Are you really sure that at your both workstations you have exactly the same setup? I mean: source code, libs versions, jdk version, tomcat, maven etc? Also you can try to purge your local maven repository (`m2` in your home directory).

Comment: Yes. As you can see, at both logs (lines 4, 8, 18, 22*, 58, 74) they have same setup. I'll try it.

Comment: Indeed, almost everything is the same - but notice that you have a slightly different JVM: `1.8.0_65-b17` vs `1.8.0_66-b17` on your work machine. Also you may consider using **current stable Weld** version  (I strongly recommend this).

Comment: @G.Demecki It works! Now I'm using last stable version of Weld (today, `2.3.1.Final`). Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to summarize discussion in the comments: it turned out that problem has been caused by a very unstable Weld version.

BTW: personally I do not recommend using an unstable Weld version. Because stable versions have already more than enough bugs.